# How do I use objects imported from a module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a problem using a class from a module.

module: http://pastebin.com/A3UQ2Ppy

```
def ClassName(object)
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    def method(self):
        print 'big success'
```

script:  http://pastebin.com/BqVthvG0

```
import module
object = module.ClassName(1337)
print object.method()
```

This is essentially what I am doing in my code, and I am getting the error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'method'

Comment: Please post your *real* code; you probably added a function somewhere with the same name as the class, and no return statement.

Comment: Also: note that `ClassName.__init__()` *requires* a parameter, but your `module.ClassName()` code doesn't pass one in. You should have gotten an exception on that line instead.

Comment: My real code is a bit long, but I'll make a pastebin.

Comment: And the *full* traceback you get is?

Comment: File "C:\NetSci\Research Project\redditScript6.py", line 30, in <module>
    NetworkA.add_node(comment)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_node'

Essentially what's up top.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me, no such exception is returned.

Comment: That's never good.. Any ideas?
I'm using sublime text 2 if that plays a factor.

Comment: Remove any bytecode files in the project (`find . -name \*.pyc -delete`), and try and run again.

Comment: Wait, just reproduced the problem, will investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define a class, you defined a **function**:

```
def Network(object):
    def __init__(self, dimensions):
        self.dimensions = dimensions
```

Make that a class:

```
class Network(object):
    def __init__(self, dimensions):
        self.dimensions = dimensions
```

Next exception then is that you cannot assign to a set:

```
self.nodes = {'all'}
for i in range(dimensions):
    self.nodes['dimension '+str(i)] = []
```

you probably wanted `self.nodes` to be a dictionary:

```
self.nodes = {'all': []}
```

Comment: Nice catch, but now I'm getting another error I don't recognize.


I'm trying to format this properly..

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Dropbox\NetSci\Research Project\redditScript6.py", line 23, in <module>
    NetworkA = dAll.Network(1)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Dropbox\NetSci\Research Project\dAll.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.nodes['dimension '+str(i)] = []
TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @user2899752: fixed that too for you. You'll then get a keyerror, after a while, but lets not make this into an interactive debugging session. I've helped you with your initial problem, plus one bonus.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it from here :) I accepted your as the answer if that's what you mean by plus on bonus.